# Edit '/res/drawable' from '.apk'

Tags: android, apk, drawable

I have an `.apk` application which has horrible graphics, so I've uncompressed it and I've edited most of the textures.

But, when I try to compress it again and install it, Android says "Application couldn't be installed" (not literally). If I don't make changes in the textures the application gets installed, after uncompressing it too.

Is there a way to modify files from an .apk? The app isn't mine and I obviusly haven't changed the names of the files. The new textures have a different resolution, may this be the problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simple try to open the apk with 7zip (do not extract) and replace the file with the same name.

But the safe way to do it is to use apktool. You can extract it, replace some files and re-assemble it with the apktool.

Don't forget to sign the apk and zip-align it.

Check it out at this page http://www.xda-developers.com/android/guide-to-decompiling-and-recompiling-with-apktool/

Comment: Align, sign, **and manually uninstall the original package** as you cannot install an upgrade signed with a different signature from the original.  This will of course mean losing all local data of the app.

Comment: Yes, this is the cost he has to pay for it.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to sign the application with the same certificate as the original application was signed with. If you do not have access to that certificate, you will need to change the application package and publish it as effectively new application.